# Snowflake: Launching a task outside of it's scheduled time

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a task:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK TASK_1

    WAREHOUSE = WAREHOUSE
    SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 30 1 * * * America/Detroit'
    AS
....
```

This runs at 1:30 am daily.
Is there a way to execute this query on demand?
i.e. something like:

```
TRIGGER TASK TASK_1;
```

Comment: You should choose an answer.

Answer (score 2):

mRainey's answer is right. You can't schedule a task outside of a schedule or task dependency. That's the correct answer to the OP's question.

For others though who stumble upon this answer, you can make scheduling a task at a different time easier on yourself:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SCHEDULE_TASK_AT_TIME"(TASK_NAME VARCHAR, HOUR float, MINUTE float)
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT

    AS $$

    var return_rows = [];

    var task_name = TASK_NAME;
    var h = HOUR;
    var m = MINUTE;

    var default_timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';

    var new_chron = 'USING CRON ' + m +  ' ' + h + ' * * * ' + default_timezone;

    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `
        DESCRIBE TASK IDENTIFIER(:1)
    `, binds:[task_name]});
    res = stmt.execute();

    res.next();
    var old_chron = res.getColumnValue(8);

    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `
        ALTER TASK IDENTIFIER(:1) SUSPEND
    `, binds:[task_name]});
    res = stmt.execute();  

    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `
        ALTER TASK IDENTIFIER(:1) SET SCHEDULE = :2
    `, binds:[task_name, new_chron]});
    res = stmt.execute();   

    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `
        ALTER TASK IDENTIFIER(:1) RESUME
    `, binds:[task_name]});
    res = stmt.execute();  


    return_rows.push('Old Chron: ' + old_chron);
    return_rows.push('New Chron: ' + new_chron);

    return return_rows;

    $$;
```

Then you can schedule your task like this, which would run at the next 22:38:

```
call SCHEDULE_TASK_AT_TIME('DEMO_TASK', 22, 38);
```

The output of this procedure gives you the old chron time and the new chron time so you can easily set it back when you're done.

Just be sure to be careful w/ this and notice its limitations - in my version you have to hard-code the timezone for example.

Also, I didn't look into whether you can set up a chron to execute just once, so whatever hour and minute you set it to, it'll run like this every day unless you take further action.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there’s no way to explicitly execute a task outside of either a schedule or task dependency.